# Запустить ffmpeg через cmd с помощью С++

Tags: c++, cmd, ffmpeg, clr

суть задачи такова: есть код который должен конвертировать видео с одного формата в другой. Я использую CLR и ffmpeg. Я опишу пока саму проблему локально, ибо код большой а проблема, как мне кажется, в одном участке:
Я решил вызывать функцию system() и передать в нее параметр cmd пути к ffmpeg и это работает, вторая же часть которая должна выполнять конвертацию `ffmpeg -i Video.mp4 Video.mov`  - нет

Цельная строчка выглядит вот так: `system("cmd.exe /k cd ffmpeg/bin/ && ffmpeg -i Video.mp4 Video.mov");`

Как я уже сказал проблема начинается после **&&** оно попросту не хочет работать не с **&&** не без них, по документации этот символ призван разделить команды на две части и выполнить их, но выполняется только первая часть.

Основной вопрос такой: Как мне правильно записать в system() команду чтобы она отработала
Исходники: https://fex.net/ru/s/ezbancv

Comment: А в кавычках - `system("cmd.exe /k \"cd ffmpeg/bin/ && ffmpeg -i Video.mp4 Video.mov\"");`?

Comment: Огромное спасибо, столько мучений а вся проблема была в кавычках.
Теперь осталось сделать чтобы на месте первого видео была переменная с названием файла. Буду дальше шаманить со строкой)